# Error in getting Breeze configureMetadataStore

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

I'm working on a SPA using the Hot Towel Template. I'm currently facing some issues

I'm getting an error on the datacontext.js

[services/datacontext]

Error retrieving data. unable to locate property: CompanyName on entityType: Company:#Atlas.Web.Models

But, the Company Model has a property called CompanyName

Thank in advance for your help guys !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was very simple - got it from John Papa on the Pluralsight SPA Jump Start Discussion Forum!

"...when the properties come to the client they are translated to camelCase. try companyName..."

Sorted!

Thanks @JohnPapa

Comment: after almost three days trying to find the answer finally found it! and the solution was to remove a line of code :).
Thank you @EdsonF!

Comment: I had same error, it was caused by not adhering to the camelCase naming convention in my js code. The solution was to use find/replace to ensure that all references to entity properties used the correct convention